# jquery , Ajax or PHP : Run Script at a specific time or perform action in the background

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am looking for a script which can run at a specific time or at a pre-defined regular intervals.

The issue is like this..... I am pulling some external content to my website and I want it to be updated at regular intervals. So what I thought was......

1. if I could use some sort of script in my `index.php` file,  which will check for some time stamp and if that time stamp is more than some specified minutes / hours, then it performs some specified action.
2. If I can load this file via Ajax in the background, every time someone visits my site and the index.php file is run. Why Ajax because I don't want this to effect the main-page load time of my site.

I don't want to use any CRON for this hence need an alternative solution.

Is it possible to do so? If yes how?

**Please note :** My programming knowledge is very new. I have just started learning it so kindly be explain the process in detail.

Comment: learn using cron, it's not complicated..

Comment: "Don't want" or "can't"? If it's "don't want", is there a reason besides mere dislike? It is the right tool for this type of job - you *could* pound a nail with a glass bottle because you don't like hammers, but it will be more work and worse result than if you used the proper tool. (don't worry, cron is quite simple) If you really, really *can* not, I'd go with your option #2, but it is a brittle hack with multiple caveats (what if nobody with JavaScript visits your site for some time?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some solution:

1. Use [jQuery timer plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers) which abstract `setTimeout()` & `setInterval()` functions
2. [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), it will allow you to send data to the browser without the browser explicitly request it.

Comment: Hey buddy thanks for a lovely suggestion specially about the `jquery.delay` method. It looks like something that should suit me. If it is not too much trouble to you, may I request you to kindly help with a bit more detailed code as I am very new to programming and specially jQuery, I am having difficulty implementing it.

Comment: I removed this option since I just come back from the doc and it won't wait while the loop is running.
Use jquery timer plugin which very simple of use

Answer (score 0):

CRON however would be the way to go ...

You could write a bash script if you are using linux and then trigger that via CRON. You could also call that bashscript via php.

How are you pulling the external content to your website? 
It really depends on how you pull your data?

Comment: yes I know that and CRON is not what I am looking for as I mentioned that very clearly in my question. I have some reasons for the same. Please do not post suggestions as answers. Kindly use comment section for the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you are using Windows, but why not use Task Scheduler on your box to do it?
Link from google 
[here](http://weblogs.asp.net/steveschofield/archive/2006/09/28/Schedule-a-task-to-call-a-webpage-using-Task-scheduler_2E00_.aspx)

Just have the php script do what needs to be done when loaded, everytime.  I'm sure there's a more simple solution without knowing any vb but I haven't looked much.

Or, leave the php page that does the scraping open on a box somewhere, and set a meta refresh on it for 5minutes

Answer (score -1):

CRON is the best option, you can call a php script directly by using php cli.

Comment: Yep I know that but as I mentioned in my question, that is not what I am looking for. Please do not post suggestions as answers. Kindly use the comments section for the same.