# How the check if user closes the window/browser/shuts off computer?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I know there is a way to check if the user leaves your webpage, but what I really need is a way to check if they are still there. I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a call to a PHP script on regular intervals in JS letting the server know the user is still on.

This question/answers might help [jquery , Ajax or PHP : Run Script at a specific time or perform action in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803040/jquery-ajax-or-php-run-script-at-a-specific-time-or-perform-action-in-the-bac)